# Encrypt Content by RSA in Android / Java

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, public-key

```
public static String encryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key)
        throws Exception {

    byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

    X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
    Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    return new String(cipher.doFinal(data));
}
```

I have a public key, like `MFWww.........EAAQ==`. When I pass the string to that argument, the encrypted message is some unknown characters. Therefore I suspect I should do something on the key before passing it to the function. But I don't how could I make it. So see anyone can help.

Thank you

Comment: See BouncyCastle and Jasypt libraries, but I'm not sure if you will be able to use them on android

Answer (score 2):

Never, ever, ever pass arbitrary binary data to the `String` constructor. You don't have encoded *text*, you have arbitrary bytes. That's not what the `String` constructor is for.

Ideally, don't represent the binary data as text at all - but if you *have* to, do so using base64 or hex, which will encode arbitrary binary data in ASCII.